# PHP SQL pagination by name

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I'm making a website with my movies and am trying to make the pagination by last id, date, views, and rating.

I can easily make the pagination by last id just by querying the database

```
SELECT * 
FROM movies 
ORDER BY movie_id DESC
```

then, with php make the pagination.

Now, my question is how to make it list by the other options? i can make it work with xml files but would like to know if there is a way to do this with a simple query.

my movie looks like this:

```
 movie_id   movie_title  movie_subtitle  movie_desc  movie_data  movie_views  movie_rating
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple query will be the best and easy solution write a query with required where clause and then just appy the limit and offset values.

Comment: tks =) was really simple. i was just looking at the returned array from the wrong angle... Anyway, thanks again